# Loop with each iteration only happening after jQuery deferred when/then possible without recursion?

Tags: jquery, loops, recursion, jquery-deferred

I want to call jQuery deferred functions in a loop but each iteration should wait for the previous iteration to complete using the deferred `when()`

```
  function (num_of_iterations) {

    var arr = [];

    for (var i = 1; i < num_of_iterations; ++i) {
      arr.push($.getJSON( ... 1 ... ));
      arr.push($.getJSON( ... 2 ... ));
      ...

      $.when.apply($, arr).then(function() {
        // somehow do the next iter. only now that all the asynch getJSON's are done
      });
    }
    return;
  }
```

Now of course since `getJSON` is asynchronous all the requests in all iterations will actually be sent before any of the `when`s are invoked.

I realize I can achieve this using recursion by calling a function that wraps what I have here in the `then`.

**But I'm wondering if there's some technique I'm missing to use instead of recursion.** I'm always worried about recursion using up the stack at some point in the future. The parameter `num_of_iterations` could be potentially quite large.

Can I use `pipe()` for this? I'm having a lot of trouble grokking the documentation for it with all its talk about filtering...

Answer (score 1):

I think you could use pipe chaining in this case.  Check out this working jsfiddle and let me know if this is more or less what you are looking for.  http://jsfiddle.net/tchaffee/Df3ay/3/

Comment: Just a note to mention that `.pipe()` is now deprecated in jQuery and that `.then()` subsumes its function mainly for reasons of compatibility with other JavaScript implementations of the deferred/promise concept.

Answer (score 0):

Function chaining and recursion is a pretty natural thing in asynchronous JavaScript. As seen in the for statement, your loop will run 10 times. That means you will also have a recursion stack of 10, so there is really nothing to worry about the stack size (unless you screw up your return condition and it runs forever).

Comment: Well that's just simplified example code. The real number comes from an external API which only increases over time and I want to allow for the future, as well as satisfy my curiosity. I'll update my example...

Comment: Well I quickly tested it and got a too much recursion error around numbers of 30000 (if you are making several requests for each loop that might mean that you will be easily making more than a hundred thousand requests - that's probably something to worry about first). That said, you might want to also look at async.js https://github.com/caolan/async