# Next iteration of $.each when received AJAX-content

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous, jquery-deferred

The question has been [asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8931563/loop-with-each-iteration-only-happening-after-jquery-deferred-when-then-possible), but it is almost four years ago and maybe there is a better solution.

I have a $.each-loop where **sometimes** additional data is being fetched via ajax.

I am bulding an object with the fetched data, after the loop there is a function that generates HTML from the object. **The problem is that the loop finishes before the ajax data arrives.** If I place an alert in the HTML-generating-function the content is loading properly.

I am searching for a solution that calls the HTML-generator-function only when the loop and all ajax calls are finished. Maybe it is a solution to count the started Ajax requests and wait if all of them are finished?

I believe jQuery deferred is the right solution for me but I do find only examples where everything stays inside the loop. Can someone help?

I have stripped down my code to the most important things:

```
//goes through each testplace -->main loop
$.each(jsobject, function(key, value)
{
 //build object together...
  for (var i = 0, numComputer = jenkinsComputer.contents.computer.length; i < numComputer; i++)
  {
    //If the testplace is in both objects then fire AJAX request
    if (jenkinsComputer.contents.computer[i].displayName == key) //<<<This can happen only once per $.each loop, but it does not happen every time
    {
      //next $.each-iteration should only happen when received the JSON
      var testplaceurl = jenkinsComputer.contents.computer[i].executors[0].currentExecutable.url;
      $.when($.getJSON("php/ba-simple-proxy.php?url=" + encodeURI(testplaceurl) + "api/json?depth=1&pretty=1")).done(function(jenkinsUser) 
      {
        //build object together...
      });
    }
  }

}); //End of main Loop ($.each)
generateHTML(builtObject);
```

It would be great if someone could give me an advice how to do it.

Comment: Just a little tip : AJAX in a loop is never a good idea. It may seem simpler, but it's better to let the server side do the loop.

Comment: The whole script is being run on our local network and there are most of the time only 5-10 short ajax calls so there is no network problem here. It would be great if there is an javascript solution for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
var thingstodo = $(jsobject).length;
var notfired = true;
$.each(jsobject, function(key, value)
{
 //build object together...
  for (var i = 0, numComputer = jenkinsComputer.contents.computer.length; i < numComputer; i++)
  {
    //If the testplace is in both objects then fire AJAX request
    if (jenkinsComputer.contents.computer[i].displayName == key) //<<<This can happen only once per $.each loop, but it does not happen every time
    {
      //next $.each-iteration should only happen when received the JSON
      var testplaceurl = jenkinsComputer.contents.computer[i].executors[0].currentExecutable.url;
      $.when($.getJSON("php/ba-simple-proxy.php?url=" + encodeURI(testplaceurl) + "api/json?depth=1&pretty=1")).done(function(jenkinsUser) 
      {
        //build object together...
        thingstodo--;
        if(thingstodo === 0 && notfired){
            notfired = false;
            generateHTML(buildObject);
        }
      });
    }else{
        thingstodo--;
    }
  }

}); //End of main Loop ($.each)
if(thingstodo === 0 && notfired){
    generateHTML(buildObject);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is short untested example about the solution. I hope this to give you idea.

```
// I guess that jsobject is array ..
// if it is not object you can use something like:
// var keys = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(jsobject)
(function () {
    var dfd = $.Deferred();

    function is_not_finished() {
        return jsobject.length > 0 && jenkinsComputer.contents.computer.length > 0;
    }

    (function _handleObject() {
        var key = jsobject.shift();
        var displayName = jenkinsComputer.contents.computer.shift().displayName;

        if (displayName == key) //<<<This can happen only once per $.each loop, but it does not happen every time
        {
            //next $.each-iteration should only happen when received the JSON
            var testplaceurl = jenkinsComputer.contents.computer[i].executors[0].currentExecutable.url;
            $.getJSON("php/ba-simple-proxy.php?url=" + encodeURI(testplaceurl) + "api/json?depth=1&pretty=1").done(function(jenkinsUser)
            {
                //build object together...
                if(is_not_finished()) {
                    setTimeout(_handleObject,0);
                } else {
                    dfd.resolve();
                }
            });
        } else if (is_not_finished()) {
            setTimeout(_handleObject,0);
        } else {
            dfd.resolve();
        }
    }());

    return dfd.promise();
}()).done(function () {
    generateHTML(builtObject);
});
```

Comment: You are blocking the whole execution when doing an ajax request rather than letting it run asynchronosly.

Comment: Hmmm. In fact $.each is sinchronous. Your solution is OK 
  if the sequence of received data is not important because 
  you send the requests simultaneously. The key here is "next iterations when receive". 
  We can also develop something like $.eachAsinc that depends from promise. Also in your case $.when is unnecessary because $.getJSON return promise.