# async http requests servicing

Tags: javascript

My page sends several HTTP requests in background. The requests are triggered by some user actions. Some user actions can cause redirect - and here we have a problem: we want redirect to happen only when all the requests were sent.

The question is: is there any Javascript library you can recommend that would allow to wait for all the reports to be sent and trigger redirect only after?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use jQuery Deferred pattern which allows you to chain (AJAX) objects and

- have success callback if all complete succesfully
- have fail callback if any of the requests fails

http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/

Example:

[How to chain ajax calls using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8612894/how-to-chain-ajax-calls-using-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

With [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) you can probably take advantage of [`ajaxStop`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStop/) event, which is triggered when *all* AJAX calls are done (no more pending connections). [Here is an example](http://jsfiddle.net/nurkiewicz/uEm45/):

```
$(document).ajaxStop(allDone);

function allDone() {
    console.info("Now redirecting");
}

$.getJSON('/echo/json/', function() {
    console.info("First done");
    $.getJSON('/echo/json/', function() {
        console.info("Third done");
    });
});
$.getJSON('/echo/json/', function() {
    console.info("Second done");
});
```

No matter what will be the order of responses, the `allDone()` callback is always executed last.