# multiple ajax requests in for loop

Tags: javascript, ajax

As the title states I am sending multiple ajax calls in a for loop. One for each entry in an array.

```
for (var i = 0; i < myArr.length; i++) {

  var request;
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else {
    request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  request.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (request.readyState === 4 && request.status === 200) {
      outstandingRequests--;
      if (outstandingRequests === 0) { 
        //some processing would happen in here
      } else {
        //be patient as more requests need to return
      }
    }
  }
  request.open("GET","some_ajax_page.php", true);
  outstandingRequests++;
  request.send();
}
```

When the request is sent outstandingRequests in incremented and decremented when a response is received. If outstandingRequests is 0 then we have returned from all requests.

My understanding is that because I have declared `var request;` inside the loop body, `request` will be local to only that iteration of the loop. Similarly `var i = 0;` in the `for` loop initialisation will mean that `i` is local to the `for` loop. Therefore the function declared at `onreadystatechange` should be called when each request returns.

This is true however only the last request ever has a `readystate` of 4 and a `status` of 200, so `outstandingRequests` never gets decremented until the last request returns and therefore never makes it back down to 0 for the extra processing. As each request is a separate request, I expect that all requests should get to a `readystate` of 4 and a `status` of 200.

I have tried googling and checking on **SO** for answers before posting but most contain jQuery or are different problems where only one ajax call is sent. In my example I can see all expected calls being made to the server.

Is my understanding wrong? or am I understanding correctly but have overlooked something else.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you want to make ajax call synchronous so that ,the next call will wait till the first call is finished else use ajaxq

Comment: not necessary, Quentin has the right answer - javascript doesn't have block scope, it has function scope

Comment: @KarthickKumar — No. Don't do that. https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/#sync-warning

Comment: @Quentin ,thanks for the update

Comment: check with this may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12317887/chaining-multiple-ajax-calls-with-jquery-deferred-objects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My understanding is that because I have declared var request; inside the loop body, request will be local to only that iteration of the loop.

No. `var` declares a variable with **function** level scope.

You need `let` ([limited support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let#Browser_compatibility)) for **block** level scope.

Move the body of your loop into a function and then call that function from inside the loop.

Comment: Thanks, but it looks like let block level support has been dropped.

Comment: @Chris — You need to explicitly declare that you are using JS 1.7 too. Move the body of the loop into a function instead.

Comment: Moving the body into a function now makes my code react as expected. Thanks, also for clearing up my misunderstanding.  I did upvote your answer but I have no reputation so it doesn't show.